# site will not redirect to custome page and throw 404 error in asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing, http-error

I don't know this question is already asked or not. But i am stuck in one problem.

I have one CMS application in that some page are static and some are dynamic.

When i access url using http://abc.com/abc.aspx

Now in this case if abc.aspx is cms page then it will redirect me to that page but if it is not cms page then this will redirect me to the my custom page http://abc.com/page-not-found.aspx

Now my question is that if i write only http://abc.com/abc then it will didn't redirect me to the http://abc.com/page-not-found.aspx but it will throw me the error 404 page or directory not found.

Now I have to check two things

1) if any custome page is not there then it will display http://abc.com/page-not-found.aspx

2) when http://abc.com/page then it will also redirect me to http://abc.com/page-not-found.aspx

Please help me our from this. This will work fine in my local but only problem in live environment.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
AB Vyas

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look into Handlers in your web.config .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy(v=vs.100).aspx